# PowerShell Not Saving XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a simple following script , so i add a header in my web.config

```
$webConfigPath = Resolve-Path "MyFolder\Web.Config"
$webConfig =  [xml](get-content($webConfigPath))
$targetNode =  $webConfig.configuration.'system.webServer'.httpProtocol.customHeaders
$newNode=$webConfig.CreateDocumentFragment()
$newNode.InnerXml= "<remove name='$headerName)'/>"
$targetNode.AppendChild($newNode)
$webConfig.Save($webConfigPath)
```

But this is not saving the changes... The path is correct, if i print

`$webConfig.configuration.'system.webServer'.httpProtocol.customHeaders`

i get my actual nodes there. Where am i missing things ?

Thanks !

Comment: If i change the config path, it saves correctly to another file if i change it to
$webConfig.Save("C:/test.xml")... it works... why ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your command is trying to save to your starting point. See here:

> ```
> $webConfigPath = Resolve-Path "MyFolder\Web.Config"
>
> $webConfig.Save($webConfigPath)
> ```

In other words, your script is trying to save your gathered data to the command in the $webConfigPath variable, which is why when you specify a different file path it saves properly. A simple fix for this is, as you have done, to change the resulting file path. If you need to use that path for further commands in your script, you can throw the file path into its own variable:

```
 $savePath = "C:/test.xml"
```

...allowing you to use the variable instead of typing out the path again.

Hope this helps answer your question!